# GAE datastore strange bloat

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

i have an python-based GAE application (on master/slave datastore) and recently noticed really strange thing: datastore size is much bigger than expected, but only in the Dashboard. And this is not connected to user activity, app is quite lichweight/simple and not really high-loaded at all

Besides that i proactively deleting all unused entities to stay below 1Gb quota but still  datastore size is not going down, it is going up instead. for now it is over 4Gb and counting!

To prove my point of view (why my case is strange): here screenshots of datastore admin page and datastore statistics both shows numbers which are much easier to believe
plus.google.com/photos/113319821637049481863/albums/5722673784686937649

may be i overlooked something... i just whant to delete "invisible entities" which take all of my billable space after all
any help greatly appreciated

UPDATE:
After migrating my data away from this app i deleted ALL data, ALL indexes and wait more than day

What i expected: app should be empty, datastore size should be almost zero (no entites, no indexes, nothing except small backups in blobstore).
What i get: Datastore size is >5Gb and not dropping. In empty project!

Something really broken here :( I can give "guest" access to project for any developer to show this is not a joke.

Proofpics:
https://picasaweb.google.com/113319821637049481863/GaeStrange#5723740881320880066

https://picasaweb.google.com/113319821637049481863/GaeStrange#5723740855735209986

So there is a question to google team: how can i "reclaim" free space or get information about what exactly occupying so much space?

UPD2. Seems like issue is fixed. Datastore size suddenly drops to expected zero! Hooray :)

Comment: Didn't they recently change the panel to take into account the size of the indexes as well as the data? I think it used to be that the dashboard and statistics tab would show the same, but now the dashboard # is the same as the one in quota details which would be the # you get billed on.

Comment: i also suspected for indexes (but in my case i disabled all default indexes and have several custom indexes). to check it yesterday i 
1) made backup of needed entities 
2) removed all indexes from index.yaml and did vacuum_indexes
3) deleted all entities via datastore_admin. 
but size raised to 5.1Gb!!! it like miracle, but i do not want to pay for it :)

i just started migration to newly created app...

Answer (score 0):

That's weird.

This is just a guess, do you have other versions of your application?  It might be that the data is being used by an old version.  You can select the version in the admin view from the bar near the top.

Comment: no, i have one version only. there is even more strangenes: i made backup of needed entities and removed all indexes and did vacuum_indexes and *deleted* all entities via datastore_admin.
but size raised to 5.1Gb!!!

for now i creating another app and will migrate all data

Comment: I thought maybe indices, or maybe mapreduce operations are leaving junk, but in my datastore admin page, I can see all the mapreduce junk, so that's not it.  Swithching to another app seems a good way to go, hope it doesn't happen again.